# Using Microsoft SMS Sender to send out smses in batch?

Tags: sms, bulksms

I understand that we can use SMS Sender in command line mode.
But i been getting this error same as this article http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/wireless/2003/10/10/sms.html

The smssender.exe will use the last device that was successfully used to send messages in the Windows version of SMS Sender. But I tried it many times, and smssender.exe always complains that no last device was used.

Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a new registry under HKEY_Local_Machine-MMicrosoft-> SMSSender

Copy registry to create from HKey_Current_User

Answer (score 0):

From 'Options', check the "Enable Logging" check-box. it has worked for me that way. Also it can also be used windows 7 x64 ( under the compatibility mode for XP )